# React Native render and switch with navigator onPress

Tags: react-native

I've just started to develop with React Native a week ago.
Can anyone help me with simple render and switch onPress to another view?

I've read tones of examples, but most of them are cutted or not well documents as if on FaceBook Doc pages. There was no totally completed example with Nav.

Here is what was done yet - View that should be rendered 1st:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  Platform,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';

export default class SignUp extends Component {
  buttonClicked() {
    console.log('Hi');
    this.props.navigator.push({title: 'SignUp', component:SignUp});
  }

  render() {
    var TouchableElement = TouchableHighlight;
    if (Platform.OS === ANDROID_PLATFORM) {
      TouchableElement = TouchableNativeFeedback;
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Welcome to Cross-Profi!
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.field_row}>
            <TextInput style={styles.stdfield} placeholder="Profession" />
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.field_row}>
            <TextInput style={styles.stdfield} placeholder="E-mail" />
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.field_row}>
            <TextInput style={styles.stdfield} secureTextEntry={true} placeholder="Password" />
          </Text>
          <TouchableElement style={styles.button} onPress={this.buttonClicked.bind(this)}>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Register</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableElement>
          {/* <Image source={require("./img/super_car.png")} style={{width:120,height:100}} />*/}
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>
            Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
            Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
          </Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: 'darkred',
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  field_row: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#999999',
    margin: 3,
  },
  stdfield: {
    backgroundColor: 'darkgray',
    height: 50,
    width: 220,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    borderColor:'blue',
    borderWidth: 2,
    margin: 5
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
});

const ANDROID_PLATFORM = 'android';
```

Navigator class that should render different views:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Platform,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';

var MainActivity = require('./app/MainActivity.js');
var SignUp = require('./app/SignUp.js');

class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  /*constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }*/

  render() {
    // this.props.navigator.push({title:'SignUp'});
    return (
      <Navigator initialRoute={{title:'SignUp', component:SignUp}}
      configureScene={() => {
                    return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
                }}
      renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
        {
          console.log(route, navigator);
          if (route.component) {
            return React.createElement(route.component, {navigator});
          }
        }
      } />
    );
  }
}

const ANDROID_PLATFORM = 'android';

const routes = [
  {title: 'MainActivity', component: MainActivity},
  {title: 'SignUp', component: SignUp},
];

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

It doesn't seem to be clear whether there must be `require` of a class and declaration of class as `export default`.

There is an error: Element type is invalid: expected a string, ... but got object etc

Help with examples would be great. Thx

Comment: try this return ( <SignUp></SignUp> ); and fix it as if (route.title =='SignUp')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your require call, you should either replace it import statement or use default property of require module i.e:

```
var MainActivity = require('./app/MainActivity.js').default;
```

or use

```
import MainActivity from "./app/MainActivity";
```

In ES6, require doesn't assign default property of module to variable.
See this [blog post](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/misunderstanding-es6-modules-upgrading-babel-tears-and-a-solution-ad2d5ab93ce0#.mywqtuz7s) for better understanding of require working in es6

Comment: Good, thank U - we`ve done with the 1st part of question, the 2-nd one is about how can I switch between the scenes?

Comment: Oh, that's not a big deal - done this also, thanks comrade.